# Finding all .cpp files in the users home directory

Tags: home-directory, find

How we will find more accurately all `.cpp` files in the users home directory that were modified no more than 5 minutes ago?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/find.1.html) can select files on various time conditions:

```
find ~ -type f -name '*.cpp' -mmin -5 -ls
```

The command lists the files

- in the directory `~` and it's subdirectories; There can be multiple directories.
- of type `f`: plain file, so a directory like `./foo.cpp` is not found (it is of type `d`)
- matching the shell glob expression `'*.cpp'` - which needs to be quoted, so the shell does not expand it before `find` it even sees.
- which have a modification time (`-m...`) up to (`-`) 5 minutes (`-...min`) ago.
- and shows the details similar to a `ls -l`

`-mmin` selects by modification time in minutes,
`-mtime` would select by modification time in days.

`-mmin -5` selects files changed in the last 5 minutes,
`-mmin 5` selects for changed 5 minutes ago,
`-mmin +5` for more than 5 minutes

`-newer otherfile` compares to the age of another file

`-iname '*.cpp'` would also match `foo.CPP` and `bar.cPp`

`-ls` shows file details like modification time. To get only filenames, leave it out.

That's a short summary, there are many more useful options - see [`man find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/find.1.html).

Comment: @VolkerSiegel what's the difference ? when i write with type and without type finding cpp file...

Comment: Without `-type f` you would also find directories like `./foo.cpp/`!